# Creating a caption for images in Drupal 7 Media module

Tags: media, wysiwyg

Is there a way to create a caption field on images? I have seen in the latest Media module you can add your own fields on images now but I can't seem to get them to output in the WYSIWYG module correctly or on the final page.

Modules
 - Media 7.x-2.10
 - WYSIWYG 7.x-2.4
 - IMCE 7.x-1.11

Answer (score 0):

You would need to edit the output of the media tpl file. First inspect the media html output and find any unique identifying code and then do a search in the media modules folder to find this line of code in the tpl. That's how I would do it.